# Jquery copy to clipboard - how to ignore special css & jquery characters

Tags: jquery

I am using ajax to request a unique string from my DB. This string must be copyed as it is, because an other tool can validate it.

The problem is I get an:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression
```

Probably because there are symbols in this string which are recognized as css selectors or jquery operators.

Here is the code which I use to copy to clipboard:

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
}
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/copy/pob-source/" + build_id,
    type : "get",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    //data : {'data':$.trim($("#stats-string").text())},
    success : function(response) {
        copyToClipboard(response)
        console.log("success, data updated");
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        console.log("updating data failed");
    }
});
```

In my ajax request I get the response which triggers the error:

```
copyToClipboard(response)
```

Here is the error output in the console:

[image]

So basically I am trying to find a solution, so the response is handled as a raw string.

Comment: The code shown appears to work fine (in browsers that support execCommand, anyway); and `$(...).text()` will always return a string. The problem you're having must be elsewhere -- presumably somewhere in the ajax request itself.

Comment: Probably I was searching at the wrong place, I will check other possibilities.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The error most probably comes from `$(element).text()`. Can you show an example of what _element_ contains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `copyToClipboard` function expects to receive a DOM element as input. It wraps it as a jquery object, and tries to send its `text()` contents on the way to `execCommand('copy')`.

What you're passing that function is *not* a DOM element, it's a raw AJAX response.  Here's a slightly modified demonstration of your code -- I changed it to a jsonp request so that the ajax call would work within a stack snippet:

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  //$(element).text() will be empty, because you're not passing it a DOM element, it's the full AJAX response:
  console.log($(element).text());
  console.log(element); 
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  
  //$temp.val($(element).text()).select(); // won't work
  $temp.val(element.query.results.channel.title).select(); // this will work, for this example JSON
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}

// random JSON url just so we can demo an ajax call
var apiUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22nome%2C%20ak%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys"

$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  dataType: "jsonp", // <-- changed from "get" just for demo
  contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
  success: function(response) {
    copyToClipboard(response)
    console.log("success, data updated");
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    console.log("updating data failed");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure how you're getting that specific syntax error, but you should definitely doublecheck to see what you're passing to `copyToClipboard`, and modify the AJAX `success()` function to pass along only the data you actually want, instead of the full response object; and  modify `copyToClipboard` to expect to receive the desired data in the param instead of a DOM object as input.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I modified it. It works for me this way.